# OS X app update issue with Sparkle under Mavericks and XCode 5

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, sparkle

I use the Sparkle framework to handle my app updates.
Everything worked fine until recently, when I upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks and XCode 5.0.2.

When I compile my app under OS X 10.8.4 and XCode 4.6.3, it can then be updated with no issue.
But when I compile the exact same code, with the same XCode project and the same code signing under Mavericks and XCode 5.0.2, the generated bundle can't be updated, Sparkle crashing during the update process with the following error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSDestinationInvalidException', reason: '*** +[SUPlainInstaller
>   performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:]: target
>   thread exited while waiting for the perform' terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Any ideas where this can come from?
Is it a signing problem? A compiling problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to [this post](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/).

The problem comes from the fact that Mavericks has changed the way apps are signed.
Every framework embedded in an app should be signed as well now.

To do so, I just added a "Run Script" Build Phase with those lines:

```
LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}"/"${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
IDENTITY="Developer ID"
codesign --verbose --force --sign "$IDENTITY" "$LOCATION/Sparkle.framework"
codesign --verbose --force --sign "$IDENTITY" "$LOCATION/../XPCServices/com.andymatuschak.Sparkle.SandboxService.xpc"
```

Comment: its giving an   
error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Users/SS/Desktop/Sparkle/macosx10.7'

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!!. You saved me countless hours!.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( Checking for codesign on these files shows correctly codesigned but still have this error.

Comment: Okay! Got it to work. I was using --deep flag on my main target, it was duplicating code signature.